# Twilio Chat getChannels order by most recent message

Tags: twilio

In twilio chat, is there a way to specify an order to the `getChannels()` method? Or is there a property on the `Channel` object that will tell me when the last message sent on that channel was? The `dateUpdated` property on Channel seems to be when properties on the channel were updated, not including messages sent/received.

I would like to order my channels list by the most recent messages. And I would like to do this without having to retrieve all the messages first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the `attributes` parameter upon [updating a channel](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/rest/channels#update-a-channel).

> An optional string metadata field you can use to store any data you
>   wish.

You could track time/date info of messages here.

```
# Update the channel
service = client.services.get(sid="CHANNEL_SID")
channel = service.channels.create()
response = channel.update(friendly_name="NEW_FRIENDLY_NAME", attributes="ANY_DATA_YOU_WISH")
print(response)
```

You should then be able to subscribe to a [channel event](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/guides/channels#subscribe-for-channel-events) ([JavaScript SDK](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/0.12.0/docs/Channel.html) example). As you did not specify what language you're using you will also find more details in the API Docs for iOS and Android SDKs as well.

```
// A channel's attributes or metadata have changed.
messagingClient.on('channelUpdated', function(channel) {
  console.log('Channel updates: ' + channel.sid);
});
```

Comment: This seems like a pretty clever workaround. Ideally it would be nice if the API provided a `lastMessageSent` field on Channel. But I see your logic. I have a webhook for `onMessageSent` that I could update a custom attribute on the channel indicating the last message time - and then in my client side code I can read that attribute to know how to sort the channels. This method will fall apart though if I end up with a whole lot of channels and have to page through them.